# Transitivity of Algebraicity (proof verification)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Suppose $F \leq E$ are fields.

Then define $F' = \{a \in E: a$ is algebraic over $F\}$

I want to see that $F'' = F'$

Suppose $a \in F''$; then there is a polynomial $p(x) \in F'[x]$ such that $p(a) = 0$. Now there are finitely many coefficients from $F'\setminus F$ in $p$- call these $b_1, \cdots, b_n \in F'\setminus F$. Then we also have that $p(x) \in F(b_1, \cdots, b_n)[x]$ and hence $a$ is algebraic over $F(b_1, \cdots, b_n)$.

Thus $[F(b_1, \cdots, b_n, a): F(b_1, \cdots, b_n)]$ is finite, and since the $b_i$ are algebraic over $F$ (as $b_i \in F'$), we have that $[F(b_1, \cdots, b_n): F]$ is finite as well.

Thus $[F(b_1, \cdots, b_n, a): F] = [F(b_1, \cdots, b_n, a): F(b_1, \cdots, b_n)][F(b_1, \cdots, b_n):F]$ is finite as well, and hence $F(b_1, \cdots, b_n, a)/F$ is an algebraic extension. Finally, $F \leq F(a) \leq F(b_1, \cdots, b_n, a)$ which thus means that $F(a)/F$ is algebraic as well. Hence $a \in F'$ and thus $F'' \subseteq F'$. And obviously $F' \subseteq F''$.

Thus we're done.

Does this seem correct?